# How to use exception handling to stop exceution entirely?

Tags: java, exception

```
public boolean validateInfo(Item item) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();
    errors.append(Validator.validateCommonInfo(flexPayload))
          .append(Validator.validateSpecificInfo(flexPayload))
    if(errors.length() > 0) {
        throw new Exception(errors.toString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

The above code is from a project I'm working on. I'm parsing through several items and in the case they don't contain the proper info I want to throw an exception and stop parsing through the item all together. By throwing `throw new Exception(errors.toString());` I would think that terminates the entire process. That's not what's happening at the moment. My unit tests for this are passing but I'm finding an error elsewhere that's making it evident that the exception is not stopping the parsing altogether. What would be the best way to deal with exception handling here? If there are errors I don't any parsing to occur whatsoever.

Comment: you'll have to check the rest of your code, for all we know, that Exception is caught somewhere else

Comment: Your code doesn't just ignore `throw new Exception(errors.toString());`, so if it's not terminating the process, then try debugging to see where it's being caught or how the control flow is affecting its execution.

Answer (score 0):

> By throwing throw new Exception(errors.toString()); I would think that terminates the entire process.

Why do you think that?  Throwing an exception simply causes the current *method* to exit, by "returning" that exception.

The purpose of exceptions is to communicate that the operation might fail, and thus give calling code both a way to be informed of this, and a way to handle this (e.g. retry, fallback, adopt plan B, ask user for more input, etc...).

Indeed, based on the names in your example, this is exactly what **should** be happening here.  Some code wants to ensure the `item` is valid, so it calls your `validateItem()` method to check.  In the normal case all is well, but in the exceptional case there is a problem - so the calling code can handle that (e.g. by returning 400 response code to an HTTP client; by presenting a dialog box stating the errors to the user and asking them to correct; by deciding not to go ahead with the cache update and retaining the previous `Item`; or whatever else is relevant based on what it is doing).

Killing the entire process is absolutely not what you should do in response to an invalid `Item`.  *Especially* not at this level.  Even if you really need to kill the process for some reason, this should be done at the top level, in your `main()` method (or similar top-level lifecycle methods for containers).

So to answer your explicit question "how do I stop execution entirely": the caller of this method should itself throw an exception to indicate that it wasn't able to perform *its* task successfully (due to the invalid `Item`).  And *its* caller should throw an exception to indicate the broader operation failed, etc., all the way up to the top of the stack.  These can either be explicit throws by catching and wrapping your initial exception, or they can simply not catch your exception and let it bubble up.

**Other issues**

1. Your `validateInfo()` method returns `boolean`.  Therefore, I think it's fair to assume from its signature, that the method will return `true` if the `Info` is valid, and will return `false` if it's not.  Throwing an exception instead violates the principle of least surprise.  If you *really* need to throw an exception in this case, have the method return `void` instead - the lack of an exception would then signify a valid input.
2. You're throwing (and declaring you throw) a plain `java.lang.Exception` object.  Since `Exception` is at the top of a very large class hierarchy, this includes all manner of other exceptions too, which means that callers can't be sure that the exception is due to an invalid item and not e.g. a `ClassNotLoadedException`, an `InterruptedException`, or any number of other exceptions that could feasibly occur at any point.  You should either throw a custom exception class here, or at least use something more specific like `IllegalArgumentException`.
3. Your message is going to be smushed together if there's more than one error.  Instead of appending direct to a `StringBuider`, I would instead collate a `List<String>` of errors, and then concat them with e.g. `String.join("; ", errors)` to generate the full error message for the exception.

Comment: Thanks very much!! I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question in detail.